# Why mouse always move to left-top corner of screen

Tags: mouse

My Ubuntu12.04 installed in notebook and upgrade from software-center today.
After some time, I found the mouse always stay on left-top of screen.
I try to move mouse to other position, but it always move to left-top quickly that I can't operate the system.
And it is the same problem that use notebook-mouse or use USB-mouse.
Anyone encounter my problem? Have solution?

Comment: Even I'm also facing same issue. Just that I'm using 16.04 version.

Answer (score 0):

Try forbidden your touchpad,Always a notebook encounter this problem----emmm,is when your touchpad has broken.[My English isn't good,sorry.

Comment: Yes, i forbidden touchpad, and don't solve the problem.